# AWS Lambda function returns no records if call from Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, aws-lambda

I am having troubles trying to get information back from a Lambda Function in AWS. The Lambda function is behind API Gateway.

If I run the function straight from the Lambda console or from the API, works ok. If I call it with this code returns [].

I am not getting any problems if the token is correct and I can see inside the Lambda function the parameter 'LastUpdate'.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<string> GetUpdates(long ticksLastCheck, string token)
{
    string Error = "";
    string response = "";

    object data = new
    {
        LastUpdate = ticksLastCheck
    };
    var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
    var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);

    byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    //I have tested without ConfigureAwait and did not work either
    var responseSync = await _client.PostAsync("getUpdates", byteContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (responseSync != null)
    {
         //I have tested with await and did not work either. With await ".Result" should be removed from the line below.
         var response2 = responseSync.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
                response = response2.Result;
    }
    return response;
}
```

If I call it from Postman works as well. Is there any header or parameter that Postman sends and I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. The field in DynamoDB is a string and I was sending it as a long and never converting to string.

So as soon as I change:

```
object data = new
{
    LastUpdate = ticksLastCheck
};
```

into this

```
object data = new
{
    LastUpdate = ticksLastCheck.ToString()
};
```

I am getting the expected response.

Thank you.